# Accessing an array by index within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to access a particular array by it's index within an object within an object (sorry, this may be the wrong terminology).

```
var person = {
    name: ["Tom", "Mike", "Sally"],
    hair: {
        style: ["bob", "weave", "mullet"],
        length: ["long","short","medium"]
    }
}

getDetail(length);

function getDetail(det) {
    var answer = person.hair.det[1];
    console.log("Hair " + det + " is " + answer)  //outputs: "Hair length is long"
}
```

When I do this, I am getting an error of "Can't read property '1' of undefined". Which tells me it isn't passing the 'det' variable correctly. If I take that out and put length instead, it works.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `getDetail(length)`, that's looking for a variable called `length`, and passing it into the function. Since it doesn't exist, the function gets `undefined`.

HOWEVER, when you write "myObjectVariableName`.etcetera`", it will specifically look for an index called "etcetera" - so it won't even be using your `det` argument - it's instead looking for the "det" index.

You can, instead, write either of the following.

```
myObjectVariableName["myIndexName"]

var myString = "myIndexName";
myObjectVariableName[myString]
```

Both of those will both have the same result.

So, to get the expected result, what you want to do is pass the string "length" into getDetail, and then replace `.det` with `[det]` *(darkajax seems to have written what I was going for, but I'm hoping my explanation also helps make sense of why it wasn't working)*

Comment: Thank you! This plus darkajax's comments explained/solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in your case you should be passing a string or a variable to your `getDetail()` function (`length` by itself is none, as it is not defined previously, nor is quoted), also there's the fact that if you want to use a variable to indicate the property/key of an object, you should use this type of syntax: `object["property"]`. You can change your code to:

```
getDetail('length');

function getDetail(det) {
    var answer = person.hair[det][1];
    console.log("Hair " + det + " is " + answer)  //outputs: "Hair length is long"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I hate it when it's a little mistake like this. Darned technicalities!